# How to use a Symfony2.2 service from ouside of the controller?

Tags: php, symfony

I have a service in my Symfony app I know from the controller we can use it with the function `$this->get('MyService');`
but from a script outside of my controller how should I call it?

Comment: Where is this script? Another service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to register your outside-controller class as a service in your bundle's service configuration ( i'll assume yml configuration here )

```
services:
    your_service_name:
        class:     Your/NonController/Class
        arguments: ['@service_you_want_to_inject']
```

now in your class where you want to use the injected service:

```
// Your/NonController/Class.php
protected $myService;

// your 'service_you_want_to_inject' will be injected here automatically
public function __construct($my_service)
{
    $this->myService = $my_service;
}
```

Remember for the **Dependency Injection** to happen you have to actually use this class as a service now - otherwise the injection will not happen automatically.

You can get your newly created service in a controller now as usual:

```
// 'service_you_want_to_inject' will be automatically injected in the constructor
$this->get('your_service_name');
```

There is also setter injection and property injection but that's out of this question's scope... Read more about DI in the [Service Container](http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/service_container.html) chapter of the symfony documentation.